# List<model> of ViewModel is null in POST method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I am working on the following. When I run the code, I am able to get the data in the correct form from the database via `GET` method and I am able to display it correctly in the `View`. However, on editing/changing some data, say `Type`, and on pressing `Save Data`, the `POST` method gets called, but the `studentsViewModel` value as the parameter comes as `null`. No idea why.

I have gone through similar questions on the website and other places online. But they are not having what I am exactly looking for. Plus, most of them are using `HTMLHelpers`.

Here are the code snippets:

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult StudentsDetails(int Id)
{
    try
    {
        var typeItems = _context.Type.Where(t => t.IsActive == true).Select(us => new SelectListItem { Value = us.TypeId.ToString(), Text = us.TypeName.ToString() }).ToList();
        ViewBag.TypeItems = typeItems;

        var studentsData = _context.Students
            .Where(r => r.StudentId == Id).ToList();

        var studentsViewModelData = new tudentsViewModel();

        studentsViewModelData.Students = studentsData;
        studentsViewModelData.StudentId = Id;

        return View(studentsViewModelData);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ....      
    }

    ....
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult StudentsDetails(int Id, StudentsViewModel studentsViewModel)
{
    try
    { 
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ...
            studentsViewModel.StudentId = Id;
            ....     
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ....
        }

        ....
    }
}
```

**Details.cshtml**

```
<div class="card-body card-padding">
    <form method="post" asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Students" id="studentsForm">
        ....
        <table id="data-table-basic" class="table table-striped table-vmiddle">                    
            @if(Model.Students.Count() != 0)
            {
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th data-column-id="StudentNumber">Student Number</th>
                        <th data-column-id="Type">Student Type</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            }
            <tbody>
                @for(int count = 0;count < Model.Students.Count; count++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>                                           
                            @Model.Students[count].StudentNumber
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select asp-for="@Model.Students[count].TypeId" asp-items="@ViewBag.TypeItems" class="chosen" data-placeholder="Select student type" name="selectType" id="selectType">
                                <option value=""></option>
                            </select>        
                        </td>
                    </tr>                                          
                }
            </tbody>                       
        </table>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" value="Save">Save Data</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Model**

```
public class Students
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public string StudentNumber { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Type")]
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Type Type { get; set; }

}
```

**StudentsViewModel.cs**

```
public class StudentsViewModel
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public List<Students> Students { get; set; }  
}
```

**EDIT: Adding Type class**

**Type.cs**

```
public class Type
{
    [Key]
    public int TypeId { get; set; }

    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you add `[FromBody]` attribute in parameter and try again? `public IActionResult StudentsDetails(int Id, [FromBody] StudentsViewModel studentsViewModel)`

Comment: @Win On running the code after making the changes, as soon as I press `Submit Data`, the page says: This page isn't working` and gives me a `HTTP ERROR 415`.

Comment: @Dashamlav 415 is unsupported media type -- what is being sent up the wire? Can you look in the network tab of Dev Tools in the browser and post what's there?  It feels like more of the page markup is needed to replicate your issue and provide an answer.

Comment: @Dashamlav I notice that action method name doesn't match `asp-action="Details"` vs `asp-action="StudentsDetails"`. Is this a typo in your question? Otherwise, you could not even reach to the action method. Could you show us `StudentsTable` class?

Comment: @Win That's a typo!

Comment: @Win `Students` Model is `StudentsTable`

Comment: @Stand__Sure On clicking `Submit Data`, I see that there are 3 `png` files that are being sent. Each has name: `data:image/png;base64,...`

Comment: @Dashamlav Could you show us `Type`?

Comment: @Win I have added the `Type` class to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not set id and name to `select` explicitly. Remove  `name="selectType" id="selectType"`.

```
<select asp-for="@Model.Students[count].TypeId" 
        asp-items="@ViewBag.TypeItems"
        class="chosen" 
        data-placeholder="Select student type">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Comment: I have removed `name` and `id`. On running the code, I am still getting `HTTP ERROR 415`.

Comment: And, just to mention, on adding `[FromBody]`, now the `POST` method is not getting him when the `Save Data` is pressed. On pressing the button, I am simply getting the `415` error.

Comment: Sorry, please go ahead and remove `[FromBody]`.

Comment: I removed `[FromBody]`. I am not getting `415` error. The `POST` method is getting hit, but the `Students` is coming null.

Comment: Could you show the rendered html code inside the browser?

Comment: Removing the `name` and `id` will solve the issue. If you are getting 415, It is because of some code you haven't shared in the question.

Comment: @Shyju As I mentioned in my previous comment, I removed `name` and `id`. I also removed `[FromBody]`. After this, when I run the code, I am not getting `415` error. However, I am getting my initial problem back where `Students` in the `ViewModel` that I get at the `POST` method comes as `null`. Let me know what else I need to share?

Comment: @Shyju What else do you want me to post to solve this question?

Comment: @Win What else do you want me to post to solve this question?

Comment: @Dashamlav After removing name and id, my sample project works fine. Could you create [mcv](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and upload it to GitHub?

Comment: @Win Is it possible to move the conversation to chat? I am not able to do so from my end. It will be easier for both of us to discuss in chat.